# Using calculus to prove an algebraic inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let $$f(x,y):=4\pi \left(\frac{y}{\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}x)}+\frac{x}{\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}y)}\right)+16(1+x+y)-\frac{16}{3}\frac{(x+y+xy)^2}{xy}. $$

Prove that $f(x,y) \ge 0$, for $0\le x <1, 0\le y<1$.

The [figure](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot++4pi%28y%2Ftan%28pi%2F2+x%29%2B+x%2Ftan%28pi%2F2+y%29%29%2B16%281%2Bx%2By%29-16%2F3+%28x%2By%2Bxy%29%5E2%2Fxy%2C++x%3D0+to+1%2C+y%3D0+to+1) of the function from WolframAlpha indicates the above claim is true. I'm wondering how to show this by hand?

Comment: It is undefined for $x = 0$ or $y = 0$, and apparently goes to $\infty$ there, so you need to remove those from the domain. To show the inequality, you might try showing that $f(x,y) \ne 0$ anywhere, and that it is $> 0$ at some point. It is clearly continuous, so that would be sufficient to show it always positive (a continuous function cannot change from positive to negative without being $0$ somewhere).

Comment: @PaulSinclair, thanks for the comment. I forgot to remove $x=0$ and $y=0$. So far I just have no idea of how to show $f(x,y)$ is nonvanishing in the domain $(0,1)\times (0,1)$.

Comment: @student Do you only want a proof using calculus (explicitly)?

Comment: A couple other approaches. One is obviously to show that the partial derivatives are $\le 0$ (because $f(x,y) = f(y,x)$, showing one partial is sufficient to show it for both). Then note that $\lim_{x,y\to 1} f(x,y) = 0$. Another is to show that for small $x$ or small $y$, the first term dominates the last term, and when both $x, y$ are large, then the second term dominates the last term.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, I do not know how to show the partial derivatives are $\le 0$ by hand, which seems to be rather difficult. Actually the graph of the function indicates that $f$ first increases and then decreases along a variable.

Comment: @RiverLi, yes, this is what I asked for.

Comment: the first term would be positive for the domain because both tangent and the numerator are positive there. The second term can be shown to be larger than the third term in magnitude by AM-GM inequality.

Comment: @student No problem. It is easy without using derivative (explicitly).

Comment: @person, in fact, the second term is less than the third term, due to Maclaurin's inequality.

Comment: @RiverLi, how to prove this without using calculus? I'm actually more interested in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $\frac{2}{\pi}u \le \sin u \le u$
for all $u\in [0, \pi/2]$, we have
$$\frac{1}{\tan(\pi x/2)}
= \frac{\sin(\pi/2 - \pi x/2)}{\sin(\pi x/2)} \ge \frac{\frac{2}{\pi}\cdot (\pi/2 - \pi x/2) }{\pi x/2} = \frac{2}{\pi}\cdot \frac{1 - x}{x}.$$
Then, it suffices to prove that
$$4\pi \cdot \left(y\cdot \frac{2}{\pi}\cdot \frac{1 - x}{x} + x\cdot \frac{2}{\pi}\cdot \frac{1 - y}{y}\right) + 16(1 + x + y) - \frac{16}{3}(x + y + xy)^2/(xy) \ge 0$$
or
$$\frac{8(x + y + xy)(x + y - 2xy)}{3xy} \ge 0$$
which is clearly true.

We are done.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is really a very beautiful answer!

Comment: @student You are welcome.